# count all related fields between two tables

Tags: mysql

categories

```
| id | tID | category |
-----------------------
| 1  | 1   | Foo      |
| 2  | 1   | Bar      |
| 3  | 2   | Fox      |
| 4  | 3   | Box      |
| 5  | 2   | Chair    |
```

upload

```
| id | category | data | act
| 1  | 1        | some |  1
| 2  | 1        | thin |  0
| 3  | 3        | fat  |  0
| 4  | 2        | key  |  0
| 5  | 1        | lad  |  1
```

select the category from categories and count the total upload id which has the same category id from upload where act is equals to 1.

result

```
|category| count|
|   1    |   2  |
|   2    |   0  |
|   3    |   0  |
|   4    |   0  |
|   5    |   1  |
```

What I have tried so far.

```
SELECT COUNT(u.category), c.category FROM categories c LEFT JOIN upload u ON c.id = u.category GROUP BY u.category
```

What should be the query?

Comment: What is you exact problem? Please show use, what you have got so far. SO helps you with difficulties in solving programming problems, but we will not do your work.

Comment: What have you tried yet  ? if nothing learn join,group by from these links
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: i have edited may post. please refer above

Comment: I don't understand the relationship your data set and your result set. Have you made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

A correct answer could be along the following lines. If this is not right, then you need to think more carefully about your criteria...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS categories;

CREATE TABLE categories
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,tID INT NOT NULL
,category VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO categories VALUES
(1,1,'Foo'),
(2,1,'Bar'),
(3,2,'Fox'),
(4,3,'Box'),
(5,2,'Chair');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS upload;

CREATE TABLE upload
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,category INT NOT NULL
,data VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,act TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO upload VALUES
(1,1,'some',1),
(2,1,'thin',0),
(3,3,'fat',0),
(4,2,'key',0),
(5,1,'lad',1);

SELECT c.category
     , COALESCE(SUM(u.act = 1),0) ttl 
  FROM categories c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN upload u 
    ON u.category = c.id 
 GROUP 
    BY c.category;
+----------+------+
| category | ttl  |
+----------+------+
| Bar      |    0 |
| Box      |    0 |
| Chair    |    0 |
| Foo      |    2 |
| Fox      |    0 |
+----------+------+
```